# Is It possible to edit graphically an XML with custom objects?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

everytime I put a custom object in my views, the XML editor said me that It can't render the view, so I have to edit it programmatically (on the XML).
Is there a solution to this?
I think the 90% of view's of apps on play store has custom view.

example of XML that fails:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#f2f2f2" android:gravity="right">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/messagecontainer" android:layout_marginLeft="92dp">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messagedate" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee" android:textSize="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/messagename" android:gravity="right" android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textSize="10dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#f1f1f1"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:id="@+id/messagetext" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_list" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:id="@+id/messageavatar"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" android:scaleType="center" android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

and the error is:

[image]

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pkmmte/view/R$attr
at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:410)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: Can you put your layout file

Comment: The error the XML editor gives you would also be helpful

Comment: edited with informations requested.